# Trade-off between overfitting and f1 score on test data

Tags: machine-learning, data-science, random-forest

I am training a random forest model and looking how the accuracy of the model gets affected over a range of `min_sample_split`. This the graph I got

[image]

With increase in minimum number of sample split the overfitting decreases but the f1 score on the test data also decreases from 0.755 to around 0.73.

So should I keep the overfit model as it gives better f1 score or should reduce overfit and reduce my overfit score?

Comment: Do not "tune" the size of the train/test splits, doing so is Scientific Misconduct.

Comment: Not a *programming* question, hence off-topic here; please see the intro and NOTE in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have faced a lot of issues with overfitting. If your model is overfitting by a lot, make sure you have enough training data and also stop the training if your test accuracy does not increase after a certain point (use early stopping). An overfitting model should not be considered as a 'viable model', especially if it's a huge gap in training and test accuracy. Try to reduce the overfitting gap then look at the other metrics, f1 score should not be the only factor as to why you think the model is good. Don't change your train/test split to get better results as that isn't the right way, meaning 'tune' them as mentioned in the comments.

Hope this helps! TC.